# Как задать второе условие для запроса в бд?

Tags: laravel

Как мне в запрос добавить два условия для where? Мне нужно найти пост по slug, и при этом он должен быть опубликован

```
$post = Post::firstWhere('slug', $slug, 'published_by' , true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent) несколько `where` прописываются через `and` (`orWhere` через `or`). В Вашем случае будет так:

```
$post = Post::where('slug', $slug)->where('published_by', true)->first();
```